# How many nodes does a ball of radius $r$ in the Johnson graph $J(n,k)$ contain?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry

1) How many nodes does a ball of radius $r$ in the Johnson graph $J(n,k)$ contain (Volume)?

2) How many nodes $v$ does a ball with center $x$ of radius $r$ in the Johnson graph $J(n,k)$ contain such that $d(x,v)=r$ (Surface)?

The Jonhson Graph is defined here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph

Any reference to this question would be very nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of vertices $p_r$ which satisfy $d(x,v)=r$ in a distance regular graph can be computed from the intersection array:

$p_r=\frac{b_1b_2...b_r}{c_1c_2...c_r}$

For Johnson graphs, $p_r=(^k_r)(^{n-k}_{　r})$.

Comment: thank you for your answer

Comment: does that mean that for the volume it is just the sum for i=0...r?

Comment: Yes. For $i=0$, $p_r$ shoudl be taken as $1$.

Comment: What does "intersection array" mean?

Comment: @user2679290 See [the general definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-regular_graph#Intersection_arrays) and [that of Johnson graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph#Intersection_array).